# How to get signed number representations of binary string

Tags: kotlin, binary, integer, signed

Is there a method to convert a binary string into a signed integer, for example：convert the string "11110000" into -16

Answer (score 2):

I got NumberFormatException when trying to deal with the negative numbers. I used the following for the negative and positive numbers. You can try this one.

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("11111111111111111111111111110111", 2));      

Output : -9
```